# Is Yellowjacket's weaponry powered by Pym Particles, or something else?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In addition to the shrinking power, Yellowjacket has fairly powerful laser weapons with little to no cooldown time (is "lasers" the right term?), which seem like a formidable piece of technology all on their own.

[image]

**Are these lasers powered by the same Pym Particles as the shrinking power?** Or is it some other technology?

Since I'm fairly sure the Ant-Man movie didn't touch on this at all, I'm mostly curious if this has an answer in the comics, but an MCU answer would also be welcome.

Comment: I don't think they're powered by Pym Particles but I don't know where the energy comes from.

Comment: We don't learn anything about these lasers in *Ant Man* - sometimes, lasers are just lasers.

Comment: They appear very similar to the repulsor blasts that Stark uses on the Iron Man suit. Just sayin'...

Comment: He also has a jet pack, but those seem to exist (see the Falson) in that universe, so that's less remarkable.

Comment: According to Peyton Reed (the director), Cross' version of the Pym Particles are called [Cross Particles](http://www.slashfilm.com/ant-man-alternate-ending/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [Pym particles](http://marvel.wikia.com/Pym_Particles) are not an energy source. They are the technology used to shrink and displace mass in the Marvel Universe. They were discovered by Dr. Henry Pym and used in his career as a crime fighter known as the Ant-Man.

- In later Marvel comic canon, he will also use them to grow and take on extra-dimensional mass as Giant Man.
- Whatever weapon is being used by Yellowjacket is ill-defined. In the comics, the Wasp used a form of bio-electric discharge generated from her body. Ant-man carried a small firearm for a time.

> - Dr. Henry Pym originally discovered and isolated a rare group of subatomic particles, which have become known as the "Pym Particles", which could alter the size and mass of objects or living beings.
> - Originally, Pym Particles were only used to decrease the size and mass of organic and inorganic materials. With some alterations, Pym was able to increase the size and mass of subjects as well. The Pym Particles work by stunting matter into the Kosmos Dimension when shrinking a subject or accruing extra matter from that dimension when enlarging.
> - Pym Particles can be used to reach the [Microverse](http://marvel.wikia.com/Microverse) along with the [Overspace](http://marvel.wikia.com/Overspace) and [Underspace](http://marvel.wikia.com/Underspace)

Comment: _"Whatever weapon is being used by the Wasp is ill-defined."_ Do you mean the Yellowjacket here?